# Extract shapefile value to point with R

Tags: r, gis, rgdal

I want to extract a shapefile value at a particular location. The shapefile I am using is can be found [here](http://www.marineregions.org/sources.php#iho), downloaded by clicking `Download IHO Sea Areas`. The shape file contains all the possible seas.

I can read it and plot it using:

```
require("maptools")
require(rgdal)
require(sp)

ogrListLayers("World_Seas.shp")
shape <- readOGR("World_Seas.shp", layer="World_Seas")
```

However, I would like to extract the sea value for a particular location, say

```
p <- c(-20, 40)
```

Comment: What kind of 'value' do you expect at that point? Elevation? But that should be zero by definition. Any other value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a probably an easier way but here is my take

```
require("maptools")
require(rgdal)
require(sp)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

setwd("/Users/drisk/Downloads/seas")
ogrListLayers("World_Seas.shp")
shape=readOGR("World_Seas.shp", layer="World_Seas") 

datapol <- data.frame(shape)
pointtoplot <- data.frame(x=-20, y=40)
coordinates(pointtoplot) <- ~ x + y 
proj4string(pointtoplot) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
#
#function over from package sp
test <- data.frame(xx=over(shape, pointtoplot))
combine <- cbind(test, datapol)
combine <- na.omit(combine) #only one point left
```

output for your point x=-20, y=40

```
   xx                 NAME ID Gazetteer_ id
35  1 North Atlantic Ocean 23       1912 35
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `over` function from the `sp` package:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(raster)

shape <- shapefile("~/tmp/World_Seas.shp")
head(shape)

plot(shape[shape$ID == 35, ], axes = TRUE)
points(pts)

pts <- SpatialPoints(cbind(-20, 40), 
                     proj4string = CRS(proj4string(shape)))
over(pts, shape)
```

or even shorter:

```
pts %over% shape
```

Comment: this is the best answer, 100%.